# Unable to duplicate template angular project in VSCode

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am starting up with angular. I have a basic angular template project ready, with some of my changes done in it:

[image]

When I do `ng serve`, it starts correctly in the browser.

When I copy paste it in vscode to create duplicate, it seems that it does not fully copy pastes it:

[image]

Now when I do `ng serve` inside this project folder, it gives me following error message:

```
PS E:\workspaces\angular-course\5-second-app-proj-template> ng serve
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "E:\\workspaces\\angular-course\\5-second-app-proj-template".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "E:\\workspaces\\angular-course\\5-second-app-proj-template".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
    at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:29:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
    at C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\anir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:14)
```

How should I duplicate my template angular project, to start up with new one. I went to Windows File Explorer and found that the angular project contained 28241 files, 3644 folders and is of 241 MBs. Copying this in Windows File Explorer also takes a lot of time. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to copy the `src` folder into your duplicated project. And all project config inside a `package.json` are missing. You also missing all `angular-cli` necessary dependencies.

**First**:

go into your second project and make sure all files from your first project are successully copied. i.e following: `src` folder, `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, `tslint.json`, etc...

You should go into your windows explorer folder and copy all the files and folder (excluding the `node_modules` folder) into your second project.

**second**:

if all files are copied, run `npm install` inside your new project in order to generate a new `node_modules` folder. Then `ng serve` should work fine as expected.